# Convert matrix into number of vectors in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

Is it possible to convert a matrix contains 6 rows and 4 columns into 6 vectors,
each row will be a vector.

```
m = matrix( c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7,4,8,9,4,5,0,2,5,7,6,1,8), nrow=6,ncol=3)
 m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    4    2
[2,]    4    8    5
[3,]    3    9    7
[4,]    1    4    6
[5,]    5    5    1
[6,]    7    0    8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is `split` by the `row` of `matrix` to create a `list` of 'n' `vector`s where 'n' is the number of rows of the original `matrix`

```
lst <- split(m, row(m))
```

NOTE: It is better to create a `list` instead of having many objects in the global environment.  Also, it is not clear why this is needed

Answer (score 1):

You would try this example you can get the idea.

```
> b <- matrix(1:20, nrow = 2, ncol = 10)

> sapply(1:ncol(b), function(i) paste(b[,i],collapse=","))
 [1] "1,2"   "3,4"   "5,6"   "7,8"   "9,10"  "11,12" "13,14" "15,16"
 [9] "17,18" "19,20"
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `lapply`:

```
lapply(as.data.frame(t(m)), c)
```